# Why is ComplexPlot So Slow?

Tags: plotting, graphics, performance-tuning, complex

I'm plotting the spherical harmonics on $\phi\in(-\pi,+\pi)$ and $x=\cos\theta\in(-1,+1)$,

```
Timing@With[{lMax = 4},
  GraphicsGrid[Table[
    ArrayPad[
     Table[ContourPlot[
       Re@SphericalHarmonicY[l, m, 
         ArcCos[x], \[Phi]], {\[Phi], -\[Pi], \[Pi]}, {x, -1, 1}, 
       AspectRatio -> 2/(2 \[Pi])], {m, -l, l}], lMax - l, Graphics[]],
    {l, 0, lMax}]
   , ImageSize -> 1600]
  ]
```

which produces a 5 row triangle of plots (rows are `l`, columns are `m=-l...+l`.  It takes about 15 seconds (which, honestly, seems long, but pales in comparison to ComplexPlot).

In constrast, using `ComplexPlot`

```
Timing@With[{lMax = 4},
  GraphicsGrid[Table[
    ArrayPad[
     Table[ComplexPlot[
       SphericalHarmonicY[l, m, ArcCos[Im@\[Phi]x], 
        Re@\[Phi]x], {\[Phi]x, -\[Pi] - I, \[Pi] + I}, 
       AspectRatio -> 2/(2 \[Pi]),
       ColorFunction -> "CyclicLogAbsArg"], {m, -l, l}], lMax - l, 
     Graphics[]],
    {l, 0, lMax}]
   , ImageSize -> 1600]
  ]
```

to produce a similar figure takes **substantially** longer (1201 seconds).  What gives?

### A Smaller Example

Consider, for example, just $l=4$, $m=1$.  Then, with AbsoluteTiming,

```
(* ContourPlot Real part *)
AbsoluteTiming@
 ContourPlot[
  Re@SphericalHarmonicY[4, 1, 
    ArcCos[x], \[Phi]], {\[Phi], -\[Pi], \[Pi]}, {x, -1, 1}, 
  AspectRatio -> 2/(2 \[Pi])]

(* ContourPlot Imaginary part *)
AbsoluteTiming@
 ContourPlot[
  Im@SphericalHarmonicY[4, 1, 
    ArcCos[x], \[Phi]], {\[Phi], -\[Pi], \[Pi]}, {x, -1, 1}, 
  AspectRatio -> 2/(2 \[Pi])]

(* Complex Plot *)
AbsoluteTiming@
 ComplexPlot[
  SphericalHarmonicY[4, 1, ArcCos[Im@\[Phi]x], 
   Re@\[Phi]x], {\[Phi]x, -\[Pi] - I, \[Pi] + I}, 
  ColorFunction -> "CyclicLogAbsArg", AspectRatio -> 2/(2 \[Pi])]
```

These take, 0.84, 0.78, and 127.5 seconds, respectively.

Comment: Is there a *single* input for `ComplexPlot` that runs slow that we can try?  I'm not very eager to run your `Table` command if it takes 1201 seconds.  Try for a [minimal working example](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2126/9490).  Also, use `AbsoluteTiming` instead of `Timing`.

Comment: @JasonB. provided a reduction to a single entry in the table, $l=4$, $m=1$ as the example.  Timings are still ~1 second and ~120+ seconds.

Comment: With v12.2 on my Mac laptop the `ComplexPlot` only took `23.6849` seconds

Comment: I'm on `$Version == "12.1.1 for Mac OS x86 (64-bit) (June 19, 2020)"`.

Comment: On my laptop, the small examples take ~ 0.46, 0.57 and 0.39 seconds respectively.

The large examples take ~10.5 and 6.3 seconds respectively.

12.2.0 Win 64

Comment: My timings in 12.2 on Windows 10 Pro are 1.19193, 1.09473, and 0.41098. I execute ClearAll["Global`*"]; before  each plot command and use a fresh kernel.

Comment: Ok, it seems my first step is to upgrade to 12.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I upgraded to `$Version == "12.2.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (December 12, 2020)"`.

Holding the machine (and, roughly speaking, the load on said machine) fixed, now my small examples take 1.9, 0.8, and 1.4 seconds each, and the "big" examples (the tables for $l=0..4$ and $m=-l..+l$) take 24.2, 21.0, and 15.3 seconds.  So the snail's pace does seem to be fixed by upgrading from 12.1.1 to 12.2.0, at least.